# How to group datas by week in sql?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

i'm getting table values like below table

```
 Name            City             Date
  a                1             Mar 22 2013
  b                2             Apr 19 2013
  c                3             Apr 20 2013 
  d                4             Apr 22 2013
  e                5             Apr 27 2013
  f                6             Apr 30 2013
  g                7             Jun 5  2013
```

i got values like above table. Todays date is Apr 25 2013. i need to group by those values from +7 and -7 like **Apr 18 2013 to Jun 2 2013**. Please help me to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from yourTable 
where DATEDIFF(day,'2013-04-25',[Date]) between -7 and 7
```

If you need the current date when query is running then use `GETDATE()` function instead of `'2013-04-25'`

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the current date is created dynamically condition

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.yourTable
WHERE Date >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())-7, 0)
  AND Date < DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())+8, 0)
```